# Grabbing user location with google maps v2 on android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to place a marker in the map each time the location changes. I am grabbing the Lat and Long from the `Location` and creating a marker within the `onLocationChanged()` method. Why doesn't the marker get created?

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener
{
Context context = this;
GoogleMap googlemap;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initMap();
    addTwittertoMap();

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0,
            this);
    String provider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng current = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLatitude());
    Date date = new Date();

    googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Current Pos")
            .snippet(new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString())
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
            .position(current)
            );
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
private void initMap(){
    SupportMapFragment mf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googlemap = mf.getMap();

    googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are getting location updates?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it outside and driven around and it updates.

Comment: I would zoom to the location retrieved just to check. So in your `onLocationChanged`, zoom to the location to make sure the marker is not added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LatLng current = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLatitude());` should be
 `LatLng current = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());`

Also, as an improvement to the configuration of the LocationManager, I'd suggest to setup it this way:

```
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String provider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 0, this);
```